# CaseClassShape for model with computed properties

Tags: scala, slick

When using Slick CaseClass shape, I am currently facing a situation where for efficiency reasons of a groupBy clause, I would need three columns to be stored in the relational model, while only two fields exists in my object oriented model ( the third being computed)

```
case class MyEntry(quantity:Double, time:LocalDateTime){

   val weight = time.getHour match {
     case x if x>=7 && x<=23 => 0.1
     case _ => 0.05
   }

 }

 case class LiftedMyTuple(quantity:Rep[Double],time:Rep[LocalDateTime], weight:Rep[Double])

implicit object MyEntryShape extends CaseClassShape(???,???)

 class MyTableRow(tag:Tag) extends Table[MyEntry](tag, "MY_TABLE"){

   def quantity = column[Double]("QUANTITY")

   def time = column[LocalDateTime]("TIME",O.PrimaryKey)

   def weight = column[Double]("WEIGHT")

   def * = LiftedMyTuple(quantity,time,weight)

 }
```

How does one write a CaseClassShape for such a usage, where the case class has a computed property which should appear in the relational model?

Comment: Have you tried: `case class MyEntry(quantity:Double, time:LocalDateTime, _ignoreStoredWeight: Double){...}`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the constructor is `CaseClassShape(mapLifted: (LiftedTuple) ⇒ LiftedCaseClass, mapPlain: (PlainTuple) ⇒ PlainCaseClass)`

We should be able to satisfy that like this:

```
object myShape extends
  CaseClassShape(
    LiftedMyTuple.tupled,
    { (quantity, time, ignored) => MyEntry(quantity, time) }
  )
```

If you change your case class to store weight but provide a constructor that computes it, you can get read-from-db behavior on the db->code side and compute behavior on the code->db side.

```
object MyEntry {
  def apply(quantity: Double, time: LocalDateTime) = {
    val weight = time.getHour match {
      case x if x>=7 && x<=23 => 0.1
      case _ => 0.05
    }
    MyEntry(quantity, time, weight)
  }
}
case class MyEntry(quantity: Double, time: LocalDateTime, weight: Double)

object myShape extends CaseClassShape(LiftedMyTuple.tupled, MyShape.apply.tupled)

val example = MyShape(0.0, now) // computes weight
```

Note that I'm calling `MyShape.apply` explicitly instead of `MyShape` - because we've created a new apply method the compiler will no longer automatically infer that `MyShape` means `MyShape.apply` (when it's being passed as a function).

Comment: This solution is the one I have implemented, though I was wondering what's the strategy to handle inconsistency?

Comment: If the value in my table is different from the one I compute in my case class

Comment: Your design is the thing creating that difference, but I have an approach that might work.